# Writeexcel (Rails) generated excel not opening in Microsoft office 2010

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I created an excel file using the writeexcel gem. It opens perfectly in libre office and open office but microsoft office says : "Could not open file". Anyone else faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was with the autofilter that I had defined. Since the autofilter had gone beyond the range of available data, Microsoft office was creating problems.

Comment: Just that? Is there any code you could show us to solve this?